# Python struct.unpack provide inaccurate conversion

Tags: python

I am using the python socket for TCP/IP communication (from MATLAB Simulink) and I found out that the struct.unpack does not provide good accuracy for numerical calculation.

e.g. I want to sent -0.031578948. SIMULINK encoded it into binary and when I use struct.unpack(), the result I got is -0.00314687183466. I am sure that this is not the fault of MATLAB, since when I use TCL "binary scan", it provide the same exact value (-0.0031578948). The question is, is there any way to improve my struct.unpack accuracy?  I attach my code below

```
data = conn.recv(16)
data = struct.unpack('>dd',data)
```

PS: I check my accuracy by printing the data

```
SimulinkTime = data[0]
SimulinkData = data[1]
print("Receiving Data: Simulink Time {} and Data ".format(SimulinkTime, SimulinkData ))
```

Comment: if I pack `b = struct.pack('d', -0.0031578948)` and later unpack `c = struct.unpack('d', b)` then I get the same `-0.0031578948`. Maybe it depends on system or Python version (and 32-bit or 64-bit)

Comment: maybe you should `pack` in Python and compare bytes to see if you get the same data

Comment: @furas I got the same result. But the problem is when it happen over TCP connection, maybe I'll will check wireshark and share the result here.

Comment: you could check if TCP gives you exactly the same bytes as you get with `pack()`. And next you would have to check if MATLAB sends the same bytes as you get with `pack()` I don't think problem is TCP but maybe MATLAB sends this value converted to bytes in different way and Python later unpack it with different value.

Comment: @furas I solved the problem, 1) There is a chance that I checked at the wrong time/package 2) The output from MATLAB and Python that I cross checked is not at their full numerical accuracy (some rounding are involved). When I printed the result to a txt file, both Python and MATLAB show the same result.